# Efficiently storing a GUID in text?

Tags: vb.net, guid

Our app requires us to write out a large list of `key, GUID` value pairs for export to a plain text file.

`6004, aa20dc0b-1e10-4efa-b683-fc98820b0fba`

There will be potentially millions of these GUIDs, and there may not be a lot of room on the device where the file will be written, so is there a more efficient way to print the GUID to keep the file size down?

I experimented with Hex encoding

```
Dim g As Guid = Guid.NewGuid
Dim sb As New Text.StringBuilder
For Each b As Byte In g.ToByteArray
  sb.Append(String.Format("{0:X2}", b))
Next
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString)
```

this got it down to 32 chars, each line is a bit shorter:

`9870, EBB7EF914C29A6459A34EDCB61EB8C8F`

Are there any other approaches to write the GUIDs to the file that are more efficient?

Comment: Can you store it in a database? It will be easier to query as well

Comment: no, it has to be written to a text file as specified in the question

Comment: Hex encodes only 4 bits per char and is no better than Guid.ToString().  Base64 does it 50% better with 6 bits per char, use Guid.ToByteArray + Convert.ToBase64String.  Do avoid encoding schemes that are hard to reverse-engineer in a text file, disk storage is very cheap.

Comment: How about just saving as plain guid and than compressing the file?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with previous comment, SQL would be ideal (or another DB) text files can be very unstable. Just done some quick testing iterating over millions of GUIDs and storing in text files.

Here is the outcome, basically anything more than 1 million guids would start to cause issues. You can store safely 10 million, but the file would struggle to open (on an average PC) as its > 150mb see below:

[image: GUID Testing 100-10mill]

The code I used is below for you if wanted to try out. I know its not perfect, but gives you an idea of where the time goes. Main conclusions are to append the files with a bulk append, don't try to append each GUID individually if you can help it. This saves a large amount of processing and time!

Even if you convert to other formats like base or binary, I think you will still get similar variations on the file size, don't forget, you are still just saving as a text file, binary will no doubt be a larger file size due to string length!

Hope this helps comment back if you need anything!

Chicken

```
Dim Report_List As List(Of String)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Report_List = New List(Of String)
    Dim Zeros As Integer = 2
    Do While Zeros < 8
        Dim sw As Stopwatch = New Stopwatch
        sw.Start()
        Dim CountName As String = "1" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left("00000000000000000000000", Zeros)
        Dim CountNum As Integer = CInt(CountName)

        Dim Master_String As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder

        For i = 1 To CountNum
            Dim g As Guid = Guid.NewGuid
            'Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
            'For Each b As Byte In g.ToByteArray
            '    sb.Append(String.Format("{0:X2}", b))
            'Next
            'Master_String.AppendLine(sb.ToString)
            'Master_String.AppendLine(sb.ToString)
            Master_String.AppendLine(Convert.ToBase64String(g.ToByteArray))
            i += 1
        Next

        Using sr As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("c:\temp\test-" & CountName & ".txt", False)
            sr.Write(Master_String.ToString)
        End Using

        sw.Stop()
        Report_List.Add(sw.Elapsed.ToString & " - " & CountName)

        Zeros += 1
    Loop

    For Each lr In Report_List
        Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(lr)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for this! did you try using `Convert.ToBase64String()` as suggested in the comments on the question?

Comment: I just re-run using the Base64 and the filesize dropped by 24% so this is definately better for you, also the processing time was lowered by ~ 80% (if that helps at all)

Comment: I've updated the post with the new code if you want to give that a go Cheers